# PHP - Is there a way to run array values through string/filesystem functions without a for loop?

Tags: php, arrays, function, postdata

I'm still a little green so please forgive me if there's an obvious answer to this question.  Basically, I'm wondering if there's a better, more abbreviated way, to do- this:

```
$file_ext = array();
$cust_file = $_FILES["cust_file"]["name"];

for ($i = 0; $i <= 4; $i++) {
    $cust_img_type = strtolower(pathinfo($cust_file[$i],PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    array_push($file_ext,$cust_img_type);
    }
```

I have searched for an answer and as far as I can tell you simply can't just transform an entire array with a function like you can with single variables.  Can anyone confirm/deny?  I feel like that's a lot of code just to pull the file extension out an array of post data.

Thanks!

Comment: [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map) can do just that.

Comment: That code doesn't look like it actually works the way you think it does.  Do a var_dump($_FILES) and see what it contains.

Comment: You most certainly can manipulate an entire array with one function. array_map() and array_walk() are two possible options.

Comment: INTeresting.  I just did the var_dump and it looks like the file type information is already in there so I don't even need to do this.  But thanks for the replies guys, this is exactly what I need.

Comment: Generally if you need to do the same thing to every member of an array, a foreach loop is cleaner and more reliable than a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just map each element of the array to a function:

```
$file_ext = array_map(function($v) {
                          return strtolower(pathinfo($v, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
                      }, $cust_file);
```

When you don't need arguments to the function it is simpler:

```
$file_ext = array_map('strtolower', $cust_file);
```

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I'm going to read up on array_map and array_walk.

Comment: I don't see where I can do that.  Maybe I don't have enough reputation points yet?